# Multiple entries shown for Feedly in "Connected Sites, Apps, and Services" in my Google account

Tags: google-account, security, feedly

I have a Feedly account to which I login via my Google account.

In my *Connected Sites, Apps, and Services* for Google I see multiple entries for Feedly. I tried revoking access to all of them but one, but after some logins (to Feedly) it again shows up multiple entries.

In my case at max I have seen 6 entries of Feedly. What is the reason for this?

[image: Feedly in Google account's Connected Sites, Apps, and Services]

Also every time Feedly asks me for permission to access my Google account information, which I grant. But this does not happen with other accounts like StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you access Feedly from multiple browsers/devices? Do you use any apps that feed to/from Feedly? I use Feedly from at least two computers and two Android devices, not to mention the connection between Feedly and Google+, Facebook, Twitter, and IFTTT.

Comment: (And I see four entries for Feedly in my connected apps list.)

Comment: @AlEverett: I use Feedly on two computers, one android device. Thats it.